# Defective thermostat

Tags: engine, lights

My chk engine lights occasionally comes on. Service guy said it was due to gas cap and they always solved it, engine light went off. Now, light came back on and they said I need a thermostat that keeps coolant cold. $300. Should I get a second opinion and is this a common problem? It’s a 2008 Ford Fusion. Thank you.

Comment: I would go somewhere rlse and get a second opinion. The purpose of the thermostat is to allow the engine to reach running temperature then control the flow of hot coolant to the radiator such that the engine stays within temperature limits.

Answer (score 2):

It's well worth getting a second opinion from a different workshop but it's worth pointing out that a check engine light will illuminate for any number of different reasons.  In each case it will log a fault code to the cars memory which can be read with a code reader.  It is this fault code that will be informing your mechanic on his suggested course of action so be sure to ask any mechanic diagnosing your car what fault code(s) were recorded.  They're in the format of a single letter followed by four digits.  You can then search online for other people who have encountered this code and give you an idea of what the suggested solution may be.

Comment: Definitely get the codes read at an auto parts store. They'll do it for free and it will let you know what component is throwing the error. Frankly, if your service guy didn't do this, it's time to find a new service guy.